# How to solve "The repository does not have a Release file"?

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager

Whenever I run `sudo apt-get update` I get The following error:

```
Ign:1http://ppa.launchpad.net/cpug-devs/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign:2http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:3http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:4http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Err:5http://ppa.launchpad.net/cpug-devs/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release             
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Hit:6http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease              
Hit:7http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:9http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                      
E: The repositoryhttp://ppa.launchpad.net/cpug-devs/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I understand that

```
E: The repositoryhttp://ppa.launchpad.net/cpug-devs/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
```

is the error. So how do I fix it?

[Edit]

I have found the problem is solved(I just removed the problem causing repo ).

Comment: I looked at `http://ppa.launchpad.net/cpug-devs/ppa/ubuntu/dists/` in a browser and looked at what versions of Ubuntu are supported - bionic or 18.04 isn't there which is why you are getting an error.  I don't know why you added it, but you need to remove it (or comment it out) or find another source for whatever you wanted from there as 18.04/bionic isn't supported by that ppa.   We can't provide a solution, as we don't know why you added it to your sources.

Comment: Yes, I had installed CPUG some days ago , i think that's when this repo was added.But it seems that they don't have the support for Bionic -Beaver.